# LeviCivita::shdw when I am loading FeynCalc

Tags: contexts, feyncalc

I have downloaded FeynArts-3.9 and put it in Applications already. Then, I downloaded FeynCalc using `Import[]`.

After that, I used `` << FeynArts` `` to load FeynArts-3.9 package and then `` << HighEnergyPhysics`FeynCalc` `` to load FeynCalc. There is a pop-up asked me to merge FeynCalc with FeynArts-3.9 (I think) and I type "yes". I got a lot of red messages, hence I close the Mathematica and start it again.

This time I use only `` << HighEnergyPhysics`FeynCalc` ``. However, I got the red message

> `` "LeviCivita::shdw: Symbol LeviCivita appears in multiple contexts {HighEnergyPhysics`FeynArts`, HighEnergyPhysics`FeynCalc`LeviCivita`}; definitions in context HighEnergyPhysics`FeynArts` may shadow or be shadowed by other definitions." ``

What should I do?

Thank you.

Comment: FeynCalc is actively maintained by Shtabovenko.  You may find it helpful to browse and ask your question on the [FeynCalc forum](https://feyncalc.org/forum/).

Answer (score 1):

> What should I do?

Read the Wiki and install the latest version of FeynCalc

https://github.com/FeynCalc/feyncalc/wiki/Installation#st_automatic_installation

`` HighEnergyPhysics`FeynCalc `` is version 8.2 that is 4 years old ...